# Get time when notification coming in Swift

Tags: swift, push-notification

Can I get local time when my device received notification, I mean if i received a notification on background mode, and when i click on it I want to know the time when device received it, example 10s before. Or it only config from payload when server push it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using Local Notifications you can save it by yourself,
for Remote notifications tell the server guy to send you time with notifications , 
then when a notifications is received you can save the details

I am sharing a below code how to fetch response when notification is received , I am using this code to push to other vc

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {


    let notificationTitle = response.notification.request.content.title
    let info = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    let data = info["moduledata"] as? String ?? ""
    switch notificationTitle {
    case "Notice Added":

        let vc = NoticeDetailViewController()
        vc.noticeID = data
        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        window?.rootViewController = navVC

    case "Practicework Added":

        let vc = HomeworkDetailViewController()
        vc.id = data
        let navVc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        window?.rootViewController = navVc

    default:
        print("")
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i know how to handle notification, just want to know the time must send by server. I got it.